# XDocument parsing

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

i have created a custom XDocument in c# and it looks like the following

```
<Filters datetimegenerated="28.07.2013 23:12PM">
   <SimpleStringFilter column="xxx" table="yyy" groupby="True" seperatereport="true">
   good,bad,ugly
   </SimpleStringFilter>
   <NumaricalFilter column="zzz" table = "mmm">zzz = 100 or zzz= 50</NumaricalFilter>
</Filters>
```

parsing it with in c# doesn't seem to work here is my code when i try to parse the StringFilterTags, however i get zero count from the above sample

```
var filters = from simplestringfilter in xdoc.Root.Element("Filters").Elements("SimpleStringFilter")
                          let column = simplestringfilter.Attribute("column")
                          let table = simplestringfilter.Attribute("table")
                          let groupby = simplestringfilter.Attribute("groupby")
                          let seperatecolumnby = simplestringfilter.Attribute("seperatereport")
                          let filterstringval = simplestringfilter.Value
                          select new
                          {

                              Column = column,
                              Table = table,
                              GroupBy = groupby,
                              SeperateColumnBy = seperatecolumnby,
                              Filterstring = filterstringval
                          };
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The root element _is_ the `Filters` element. The `Filters` element doesn't have a `Filters` child element.

Comment: @JeffMercado change it to xdoc.Root.Elements("SimpleStringFilter") worked fine , thank you very much please add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is searching off of the root element checking to see if it has a child `Filters` element.  Since the root *is* the `Filters` element, that obviously fails which is why you are not getting any results.

There are two ways to resolve this problem.  Just don't search for the `Filters` off of the root and your query should be fine.

```
var filters =
    from simplestringfilter in xdoc.Root.Elements("SimpleStringFilter")
    ...
```

A better way to write it IMHO would be to not query off of the root but the document itself.  It will look more natural.

```
var filters =
    from simplestringfilter in xdoc.Element("Filters")
                                   .Elements("SimpleStringFilter")
    ...
```